# How to write to csv file from a text file

Tags: python, csv, file-handling, xlsxwriter

I have text file with data like below:

```
"id":0
"value1":"234w-76-54"
"id":1
"value1":"2354w44-7-54"
```

I want to have these data in csv file. I tried with below code, but this is writing each ids and value1 as list in csv file.

```
with open("log.txt", "r") as file:
    file2 = csv.writer (open("file.csv", "w", newline=""), delimiter=",")
    file2.writerow(["id", "value1"])
        for lines in file:
            if "id" in lines:
                ids = re.findall(r'(\d+)', lines)
            if "value1" in lines:
                value1 = re.findall(r'2[\w\.:-]+', lines)
                file2.writerow([ids, value1])
```

getting output-

```
 id         value1
['0']   ['234w-76-54']
['1']   ['2354w44-7-54']
```

Desired output-

```
  id         value1
  0        234w-76-54
  1        2354w44-7-54
```

Comment: Ehat about using `file2.writerow([ids[0], value1[0]])`?

Comment: use `re.search` instead of `re.findall`

Comment: This worked, Thanks @BarbarosÖzhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it, in my opionion, is to read in the .txt file using pandas's [read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) method and write out using the [Dataframe.to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

Below I've created a fully reproducible example recreating the OP's .txt file, reading it in and then writing out a new .csv file.

```
import pandas as pd

#Step 0: create the .txt file
file = open("file.txt","w")
input = '''"id":0
"value1":"234w-76-54"
"id":1
"value1":"2354w44-7-54"'''

file.writelines(input)
file.close() 

#Step 1: read in the .txt file and create a dataframe with some manipulation to 
#        get the desired shape
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', delimiter=':', header=None)
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'id': df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0] == 'id'][1].tolist(),
'value1': df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0] == 'value1'][1].tolist()})
print(df_out)

#Step 2: Create a .csv file
df_out.to_csv('out.csv', index=False)
```

Expected Outputted .csv file:

[image: Expected .csv output]

Answer (score 0):

`findall` returns a list. you probably want to use `re.search` or `re.match` depending on your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

If your log.txt really has that simple structure you can work with `split()`:

```
import csv

with open("text.txt", "r") as file:
    file2 = csv.writer(open("file.csv", "w", newline=""), delimiter=",")
    file2.writerow(["id", "value1"])
    for line in file:
        if "id" in line:
            ids = int(line.split(":")[-1])
        else:
            value = line.split(":")[-1].split('"')[1]
            file2.writerow([ids, value])
```

The resulting csv will contain the  following:

```
id,value1
0,234w-76-54
1,2354w44-7-54
```

The comma as separator is set by the delimiter argument in the csv.writer call.

First look for a line with `"id"` in it. This line can easily be splitted at the `:`. This results in a list with two elements. Take the last part and cast it into an integer.

If no `"id"` is in the line, it is an `"value1"` line. First split the line at the `:`. Again take the last part of the resulting list and split it at `"`. This results again in a list with three elements, We need the second one.